# Prove that $\lim_{a \to 0^{+}} \int_{0}^{a} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos(x)-\cos(a)}} \;dx=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

How can I prove that

$$\lim_{a \to 0^{+}} \int_{0}^{a} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos(x)-\cos(a)}} \;dx=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can expand $\cos(x)$ into a Taylor series, keeping only the first two terms, since all the rest go to zero. You get the integral:
$$\int_0^b{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}}}dx = \sqrt{2} \arctan\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}\right)$$
Since $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}{\arctan {x}} = \pi/2$, the result follows.

Comment: Nice solution! (+1)

Answer (score 8):

Exploiting the trigonometric identity $ \cos(x) = 1-2\sin^2(\frac{x}{2}) $ and making the change of variables $x=ay$ results in the following integral,

$$ a\int _{0}^{1}\!{\frac {1}{\sqrt {-2\, \sin^2 \left( \frac{a}{2}  \right)  + 2\, \sin^2 \left( \frac{a y}{2}  
 \right) }}}{dy}$$

Using the fact that $ \sin(a)\approx a $ when $a \rightarrow 0 $ in the above integral yields

$$ \sqrt {2}\int _{0}^{1}\!{\frac {1}{\sqrt {1-{y}^{2}}}}{dx} = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}} \,.$$

Comment: There is no need to use approximation. After changing $x=a y$: $$ \lim_{a \to 0^+} \int_0^a \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\cos(x)-\cos(a)}} =  \int_0^1 \sqrt{\lim_{a \to 0^+} \frac{a^2}{\cos(a y)-\cos(a)}} \mathrm{d} y$$ Evaluating the limit by applying l'Hospital's rule twice, the answer follows.

Comment: Sasha & Chris: Nice finish.