# limit of integral function

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

As part of an investigation, a student of mine needed to evaluate the limit, 
$$\lim_{\beta\to 0+}\int_0^\beta\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos\theta-\cos\beta}}\,d\theta.$$
Mathematica gives the answer as $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt2}$, but I couldn't show her a nice way of proving this. Is there any way to do this that a (bright) high school student might understand? Or does it necessarily involve an excursion into the land of elliptic integrals?

For interest's sake: the limit arose when she was trying to see how well the circle approximates the [tautochrone](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TautochroneProblem.html.).

Comment: What about $\alpha $?

Comment: Thanks for picking up the error. It's fixed now. As you can see, it's now an improper integral.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188301/lim-a-to-0-int-0a-frac1-sqrt-cosx-cosa-dx-frac-pi/188330#188330).

Comment: Thanks! Interesting that someone else came upon the exact same limit.

Comment: You are welcome!  The same problem was asked as you can see more than 3 years ago!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you substitute $\theta = \beta t$, you get 
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1 dt \frac{\beta}{\sqrt{\cos\beta t - \cos\beta}}
\end{equation}
 and you do a Taylor expansion of the integrand in $\beta$ (essentially take the limit $\beta$ goes to $0$).

You are left with $\int_0^1 dt\sqrt{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} $, which is your result.

Comment: It seems like this question has been answered before. I'll accept this answer but then mark as duplicate. Thanks for your suggestion!